# Is it important to swing baby in cradle in two axis?

Tags: infant, newborn

I was reading that it is really important to swing newborn in cradle - in general it helps brain to develop. I also found some opinions that it is really important to swing newborn in cradle not only in one but in both axis (front-back, left-right). Is it really worth to invest into cradle which can swing in both axis?

@Edit
Sources are in polish so I won't paste it but let me try to translate below and maybe it was sponsored by cradle manufacturer, who knows but what they mentioned in article:

1. It (rocking in cradle) stimulates the brain to activity - research (there is no source here in original article) says that swinging helps in creating connections between neurons which increases the intellectual potential.
2. Affects the development of the vestibular system - that is, the part of the nervous system responsible for the sense of balance and motor coordination, which its most intense development passes in the first two years of a child's life.
3. Strengthens the muscles of the whole body - even postural muscles. Therefore, rocking is recommended for children with reduced muscle tone.

Also found something in english: https://wnm-group.co.uk/aktualnosci/n/20/why-choose-a-cradle-for-a-newborn-baby, it says:

> As scientists have shown, rocking also develops the child's
>   intelligence. Research has shown that during this movement, new
>   neurons, or synapses, are formed in the brain of the toddler, the
>   number of which significantly influences the intellectual potential of
>   the toddler.

and here: https://dreamercradle.co.uk/benefits/

> This first cradle movement stimulates the production of neuronal
>   connections in the brain, which increases the child's intellectual
>   potential. The "front-back" movement positively affects the
>   development of the vestibular system of the brain.

Comment: Can you add a source to that claim? I doubt that a cradle is crucial for brain development.

Comment: Did a cradle manufacturer tell you this?

Comment: Guys, replied as editing question because it was too long.

Comment: Michu93, editing your question is the right way to add additional information asked for in comments. Well done.

Comment: Incidentally, it seems that the reason this rocking motion is so good for babies is that it somewhat simulates the very natural situation of an adult carrying the baby while walking.  Personally I opt for a baby carrier, wrap or sling, and do it the old fashioned way!  (I will expand to an answer if I can find what I would consider a reliable source.)

Comment: To be clear, are you asking about a sleeping cradle for use when the baby is sleeping, or a cradle for use when the baby is awake?  There are markedly different implications.